# Why does newenvironment work when not using begin/end, but not with?

Tags: environments

I have two environments `ItemBroken` and `ItemWorking`. There are two differences in their definitions:

- `ItemBroken` takes 2 arguments, where `ItemWorking` takes three.
- `ItemBroken` has both a before and after defined. `ItemWorking` instead takes a third argument to not need after.

When using `ItemBroken` it works correctly until `\end{ItemBroken}` is met. This can be seen in the following Overleaf output:

[image]

MVCE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newenvironment{ItemBroken}[2]
    {
        -
        & #1
        & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}L{200pt}@{}}
            #2\\
            \begin{tabular}{ L{200pt} }
                }{
            \end{tabular}\\
        \end{tabular}
    }

\newenvironment{ItemWorking}[3]
    {
        -
        & #1
        & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}L{200pt}@{}}
            #2\\
            \begin{tabular}{ L{200pt} }
                #3
            \end{tabular}\\
        \end{tabular}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ R{5pt} L{20pt} | p{200pt} }
    \ItemWorking{Key}{Title}
        {
            Item
        }\\
    \ItemWorking{Key}{Title}
        {
          Item
        }\\
    \ItemWorking{Key}{Title}
        {
          Item
        }\\
    \begin{ItemBroken}{Key}{Title}
        Item
    \end{ItemBroken}\\
    \ItemWorking{Key}{Title}
        {
          Item
        }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ItemWorking` should be defined with `\newcommand` not `\newenvironment` as it is the blank line before `\begin{document}` is taken as the end code  (which you then do not use)

Comment: If you deleted the following blank line then the `\begin` from `\begin{document}` would be taken as the end code argument and things would go very wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a tabular then you can have a command `\foo{a}{b}{c}` that expands to `a&b&c` and use

```
   \begin{tabular}{ccc}
   \foo{a}{b}{c}
   \end{tabular}
```

as that is

```
   \begin{tabular}{ccc}
   a&b&c
   \end{tabular}
```

but you can not have an environment form `\begin{fooenv}{a}{b} c\end{fooenv}` as `\begin` `\end` form a group so that would be

```
   \begin{tabular}{ccc}
   \begingroup a &b &c \endgroup
   \end{tabular}
```

and you can not start a group in one cell and end in the other,

Note that your definition of `\Itemworking` should use `\newcommand` it only fails to give an error as defined as you have a blank line which is taken as the mandatory end code.